# Golang read file Carriage Return

Tags: file, go

Hi i have a implementation to read a file Line Feed, but it does not work to Carriage Return files the implementation is:

```
file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        ross := int32(1)
        fileValidation = append(fileValidation, p.createPharmacyPanelLoaderResultErr(pharmacyPanel, &ross, err.Error(), err.Error()))
        return nil, fileValidation, int32(0)
    }

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for i := 0; scanner.Scan(); i++ {
 line := scanner.Text()
}
```

i want to transform this function to can work with both Carriage Return and Line Feed

Comment: The default `ScanLines` function used by the `Scanner` matches both `\n` and `\r\n`. What is the input you're trying to read?

Comment: i hant to read a carrier return lines break

Comment: What does that mean exactly? Do you want to match any combination of carriage returns and newlines? The [`ScanLines` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanLines) show the default match is equivalent to \r?\n. Do you want to split on a regex like: `\n|\r\n|\r`? Do you want the `\r` to never be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I took the ScanLines function from the source code and changed it so it works with \r but now it will only work with \r and not \n or \r\n

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func ScanLinesWithCR(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }
    if i := bytes.IndexByte(data, '\r'); i >= 0 {
        // We have a full newline-terminated line.
        return i + 1, data[0:i], nil
    }
    // If we're at EOF, we have a final, non-terminated line. Return it.
    if atEOF {
        return len(data), data, nil
    }
    // Request more data.
    return 0, nil, nil
}

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Open("test.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    scanner.Split(ScanLinesWithCR)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(">", scanner.Text())
    }
}
```